# Groovy spread operator map syntax with colon

Tags: groovy

I'm wondering why this syntax is not consistent for spreading lists and maps. For example in this code

```
def list =[1,2,3]
def map =[a:1,b:2]
println "${[*list]}"
println "${[*:map]}"
```

list is spreaded with single *, and map with *:

Is it connected to how spread operator internally works? Because didn't see any other usage for *map construct (like defining an empty map with [:] makes sense to distinguish it from list).

Comment: `*:` is just an operator, like `*` or `?:` or `+`...  It's not connected to how it works internally, it's just the _"name"_ of the operator to spread maps

Answer (score 10):

The spread operator (*) is used to extract entries from a collection and provide them as individual entries.

> **1. Spread list elements:**
>
> When used inside a list literal, the spread operator acts as if the spread element contents were inlined into the list:
>
> ```
> def items = [4,5]               
> def list = [1,2,3,*items,6]             
> assert list == [1,2,3,4,5,6]
> ```

Source : http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_spread_list_elements

> **2. Spread map elements:**
>
> The spread map operator works in a similar manner as the spread list operator, but for maps. It allows you to inline the contents of a map into another map literal, like in the following example:
>
> ```
> def m1 = [c:3, d:4]         
> def map = [a:1, b:2, *:m1] 
> assert map == [a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4]​
> ```

Source : http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_spread_map_elements

Comment: I find the equivalent syntax `def map = [a:1, b:2] + m1` more readable

Comment: Yes me too but just @Vuk asked for `*:` significance so I gave him an example of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've read the documentation, but the question was why the same operator in one case use * and in another *: symbol. As groovy tends to simplify things wherever possible, guess there must be a good reason for it.

Comment: Well I am not sure why groovy creator kept it that way but as `Map` is represented as `key:value` pair, so they must have thought of keeping it `*:` as map contains `:`.